# If $A^3 = O$, what condition do the entries of $A$ satisfy?

Tags: matrices, nilpotence

$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

When $A^3 = O$ (zero matrix) is satisfied, what condition do the four real numbers $a, b, c, d$ meet?

---

I cubed $A$:

$A^3 = \begin{bmatrix} a(a^2+bc)+bc(a+d) & b(a^2+bc) + bd(a+d) \\ ac(a+d)+c(bc+d^2) & bc(a+d)+d(bc+d^2)\end{bmatrix}$

I don’t know how it is going to be.

### Post script

Thank you for the replies, I might have found the answers:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
A^3_{11} * d - A^3_{12} * c = 0 \\
(ad-bc)(a^2+bc) = 0 \\
ad-bc = 0
\end{eqnarray}
$$

But why $ a^2 + bc \neq 0$?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What, for instance, is $\det(A)$?

Comment: Yes, I got this equation: $A^3 = \begin{pmatrix} a(a^2+bc)+bc(a+d) & b(a^2+bc) + bd(a+d) \\ ac(a+d)+c(bc+d^2) & bc(a+d)+d(bc+d^2)\end{pmatrix}$.
But I don’t know how I can get the answer.

Comment: Please edit your post to indicate your efforts (and cubing the matrix definitely counts).  As a Hint:  suppose that $a\neq 0$.  Then we can divide by $a$ to get a non-zero constant times a matrix with a $1$ in one entry.  What cvann you say about the other entries?

Comment: by $O$ I take it you mean the zero matrix?

Comment: Side note:  it helps a lot if you note that $A^3=0\iff A^2=0$.  See, e.g., [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525213/a-2x2-matrix-m-exists-suppose-m3-0-show-that-i-want-proof-m2-0)

Comment: Yes, $O$ means zero matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)$ be the characteristic polynomial of $A.$ Since $A^3$
is zero, $f(x)$ divides $x^3.$ Therefore, $f(x)=x^2.$ Thus, $A$ has both trace and determinant zero.  In other words, $d=-a$ and
$bc=a^2.$ (If $a=0,$ observe that either $b$ or $c$ must zero.)

Comment: This is the way to go. I think you can improve it by noting that if trace and determinant *are* both zero then the characteristic polynomial is $X^2$ and so the condition is necessary and sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the nontrivial solution is

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 -\frac{a^2}{b} & -a \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: This misses $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ c & 0\end{pmatrix}$.